# Monomorphizing with Type Families

Tags: haskell, ghc

The following code compiles, but only with an explicit type signature in `bar`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

type family ResultOf a where
  ResultOf (a -> b) = ResultOf b
  ResultOf a = a

wrap :: (Monad rnd, ResultOf bnch ~ rnd Int) => bnch -> rnd Int
wrap = undefined

foo :: (Monad m) => m Int
foo = undefined

bar :: forall rnd . (Monad rnd, ResultOf (rnd Int) ~ rnd Int) => rnd Int
bar = wrap (foo :: rnd Int)
```

I understand roughly why the type signature is required: `foo` is polymorphic, and GHC can't tell that the only way `ResultOf (forall m . (MonadRandom m) => m Int) ~ rnd Int` is if we instantiate `m` at `rnd`. I'd like this to be true, so that GHC will monomorphize 'foo` with the correct monad without an explicit type signature. Is there some way to convince GHC of this?

Comment: One solution is to use a newtype as the output of the function, so that the type family doesn't overlap (i.e. could exist as an open family). Can it be done without a silly wrapper that simply goes on and immediately comes back off?

Comment: Do you have an actual implementation for `wrap`? It seems to me this function is inhabited by only `const ...` (and various bottoms of course). `ResultOf a ~ a` asserts that `a` is not a function type, because this cannot be true if the first pattern ever matched, but it doesn't contain a proof of such - you must construct that yourself. Typically the way to do this is to write a GADT modelling the proof and have a type class which constructs values of this proof implicitly.

Comment: @user2407038 `wrap` uses a simple type class (not shown, since it isn't relevant to the inference issue) to randomly generate function arguments, much like QuickCheck's Testable class.